# GroovyCodeVisitor says java method returns Object instead of actual type. No generics involved

Tags: groovy

I am using a GroovyCodeVisitor to check and complain if banned types are within a script. The visitor sees attempts to new Banned() but when visiting a method that returns Banned it only sees Object. Is this intentional or am i missing something. I just want to confirm the method is a plain vanilla declaration that returns plain old boring Banned and does not included generics in any form which should eliminate erasure as a potential source of the problem.

Before any jumps, I am not using SecureASTCompilationCustsomer because i am using a matcher to ban classes rather than simply adding black and white lists and other stuff which are supported by SecureASTCompilationCustomizer.

Answer (score 0):

GroovyCodeVisitor is for visiting "code". That is for example the body of a Method. The return type of a method is stored in the MethodNode, not the code part you handle with your GroovyCodeVisitor. You could use ClassCodeVisitorSupport and override visitMethod(MethodNode mn) to then get the return type via mn.getReturnType() and give that into your checking code. Of course a method's return type is only for example "Banned" if declared so. If you use "def" for example the return type will be Object.